# Change preceding sibling - CSS image transform - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this HTML (simplified)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="#"><img src="photo.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Title Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't change the order of the code and there are multiple `container`'s on the page.
I'm trying to achieve a zoom effect on the `img` when you hover on the `title`. As far as I know you can't effect the preceding sibling with CSS alone so I'm using jquery.

The `container` has a width set to it and overflow hidden but, when I get jquery to scale the `img` it seems to be scaling the `thumb` div instead.

```
$('.title').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev([type="image"]).css({
        "-webkit-transform":"scale(1.1)",  
        "-moz-transform":"scale(1.1)",
        "-o-transform":"scale(1.1)",
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Strangely this had not effect on the `img`

```
$('.title').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev(.thumb img).css({
        "-webkit-transform":"scale(1.1)",  
        "-moz-transform":"scale(1.1)",
        "-o-transform":"scale(1.1)",
});
```

Comment: `.prev()`, like most jQuery traversal methods, takes a selector in the form of a ***string***. I.E. `.prev('[type="image"]')` & `.prev('.thumb img')`

Comment: You have also omitted the trailing braces `});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse like this:

```
$('.title').hover(function(){
  $(this).closest(".container").find(".thumb img").css({
    "-webkit-transform":"scale(1.1)",  
    "-moz-transform":"scale(1.1)",
    "-o-transform":"scale(1.1)",
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippets:

```
$('.title').hover(function() {
  $(this).prev('.thumb').find('img').css({
    "-webkit-transform": "scale(1.1)",
    "-moz-transform": "scale(1.1)",
    "-o-transform": "scale(1.1)",
  });
```

By using `prev` you can only get the previous `div` with thumb class name. From there you need to traverse for `img` to reach it.